# Why jQuery is not working as per requirement

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, dom-events

```js
function displayingListAdultChild(nameSelect){
      if(nameSelect){
           firstroom            = document.getElementById("firstroom").value;
           secondroom           = document.getElementById("secondroom").value;
           thirdroom            = document.getElementById("thirdroom").value;
           fourthroom           = document.getElementById("fourthroom").value;
          if(firstroom == nameSelect.value){
              document.getElementById("displayingFourthAdultChild").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("displayingThirdAdultChild").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("displayingSecondAdultChild").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("displayingFirstAdultChild").style.display = "block";
          }
          else if(secondroom == nameSelect.value){
              document.getElementById("displayingFourthAdultChild").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("displayingThirdAdultChild").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("displayingSecondAdultChild").style.display = "block";

          }else if(thirdroom == nameSelect.value){
              document.getElementById("displayingFourthAdultChild").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("displayingSecondAdultChild").style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById("displayingThirdAdultChild").style.display = "block";
          }else if(fourthroom == nameSelect.value){
              document.getElementById("displayingSecondAdultChild").style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById("displayingThirdAdultChild").style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById("displayingFourthAdultChild").style.display = "block";
          }
      }
   }

   /*here selecting child field*/
   function displayingNumberOfChildAge(nameSelect){
    // body... 
    if(nameSelect){
             first_child_col            = document.getElementById("first_child_col").value;
             second_child_col           = document.getElementById("second_child_col").value;
             second_child_col           = document.getElementById("second_child_col").value;
            if(first_child_col == nameSelect.value){
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age").style.display = "block";
            }
            else if(second_child_col == nameSelect.value){
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age").style.display = "block";
            }else {
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
     }
     function displayingNumberOfChildAgeSecondRoom(nameSelect){
    // body... 
    if(nameSelect){
          sec_room_first_child_col      = document.getElementById("sec_room_first_child_col").value;
          sec_room_second_child_col     = document.getElementById("sec_room_second_child_col").value;
            if(first_child_col == nameSelect.value){
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_second_room").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age_second_room").style.display = "block";
            }
            else if(second_child_col == nameSelect.value){
     
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_second_room").style.display = "block";
            }else {
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age_second_room").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_second_room").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
     }
     function displayingNumberOfChildAgeThirdRoom(nameSelect){
    // body... 
    if(nameSelect){
          third_room_first_child_col    = document.getElementById("third_room_first_child_col").value;
          third_room_second_child_col   = document.getElementById("third_room_second_child_col").value;
            if(first_child_col == nameSelect.value){
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_third_room").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age_third_room").style.display = "block";
            }
            else if(second_child_col == nameSelect.value){
     
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_third_room").style.display = "block";
            }else {
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age_third_room").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_third_room").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
     }
     function displayingNumberOfChildAgeFourthRoom(nameSelect){
    // body... 
    if(nameSelect){
          fourth_room_first_child_col   = document.getElementById("fourth_room_first_child_col").value;
          fourth_room_second_child_col  = document.getElementById("fourth_room_second_child_col").value;
            if(fourth_room_first_child_col == nameSelect.value){
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_fourth_room").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age_fourth_room").style.display = "block";
            }
            else if(fourth_room_second_child_col == nameSelect.value){
     
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_fourth_room").style.display = "block";
            }else {
                document.getElementById("displaying_first_child_age_fourth_room").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displaying_second_child_age_fourth_room").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
      
      
      <div class="col-sm-1">
         <label>Rooms</label>
         <select id="rooms" onchange="displayingListAdultChild(this);" class="form-control">
            <option id="empty">Select</option>
            <option id="firstroom"  value="1">1</option>
            <option id="secondroom"     value="2">2</option>
            <option id="thirdroom"  value="3">3</option>
            <option id="fourthroom"     value="4">4</option>
            <option id="fifthroom"  value="5">5</option>
            <option id="sixthroom"  value="6">6</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div id="displayingFirstAdultChild" style="display:none;">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
            <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
               <option   value='1'>1</option>
               <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
               <option value='3'>3</option>
               <option value='4'>4</option>
               <option value='5'>5</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
            <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control">
               <option>select</option>
               <option id="first_child_col"  value='1'>1</option>
               <option id="second_child_col"  value='2'>2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="#" id="displaying_first_child_age" style="display: none;">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
               <select  class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="#" id="displaying_second_child_age" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
               <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div id="displayingSecondAdultChild" style="display:none;">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
            <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
               <option   value='1'>1</option>
               <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
               <option value='3'>3</option>
               <option value='4'>4</option>
               <option value='5'>5</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
            <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAgeSecondRoom(this);" class="form-control">
               <option>select</option>
               <option id="sec_room_first_child_col"  value='1'>1</option>
               <option id="sec_room_second_child_col"  value='2'>2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="#" id="displaying_first_child_age_second_room" style="display: none;">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
               <select  class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="#" id="displaying_second_child_age_second_room" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
               <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div id="displayingThirdAdultChild" style="display:none;">
      <label>Third Room</label>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
            <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
               <option   value='1'>1</option>
               <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
               <option value='3'>3</option>
               <option value='4'>4</option>
               <option value='5'>5</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
            <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAgeThirdRoom(this);" class="form-control">
               <option>select</option>
               <option id="third_room_first_child_col"  value='1'>1</option>
               <option id="third_room_second_child_col"  value='2'>2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="#" id="displaying_first_child_age_third_room" style="display: none;">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
               <select  class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="#" id="displaying_second_child_age_third_room" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
               <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div id="displayingFourthAdultChild" style="display:none;">
      <label>Fourth Room</label>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
            <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
               <option   value='1'>1</option>
               <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
               <option value='3'>3</option>
               <option value='4'>4</option>
               <option value='5'>5</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-1">
            <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
            <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAgeFourthRoom(this);" class="form-control">
               <option>select</option>
               <option id="fourth_room_first_child_col"  value='1'>1</option>
               <option id="fourth_room_second_child_col"  value='2'>2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="#" id="displaying_first_child_age_fourth_room" style="display: none;">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
               <select  class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="#" id="displaying_second_child_age_fourth_room" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
               <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
               <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
                  <option  value='1'>1</option>
                  <option  value='2'>2</option>
                  <option  value='3'>3</option>
                  <option  value='4'>4</option>
                  <option  value='5'>5</option>
                  <option  value='6'>6</option>
                  <option  value='7'>7</option>
                  <option  value='8'>8</option>
                  <option  value='9'>9</option>
                  <option  value='10'>10</option>
                  <option  value='11'>11</option>
                  <option  value='12'>12</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

its a room service options.
as per requirement room will visible.
when im clicking for first room so successfully receiving result.
but when trying to get all room by selecting selector field so its not working properly.
inside the option there is child option also available for selecting child. when trying to click child box 2nd instantly it also not appearing first time

Comment: That's raw JavaScript, not jQuery. You should, at least condense your own code, if you're using raw JavaScript. If you're going to use jQuery, use it all the way, even in your own mini-library. It looks like you don't have a value on the first option in your select, though.

Comment: actually this is someone else code i'm really sorry i didn't checkout. i can't figuring why JavaScript is not working properly. whenever selecting 4 number of room instead of 1 so after there also have to visible some child select field which is not working but if u goes by sequence so that will work. if you figure out then please help.thanks in advance

Comment: Your code snippet has 2 versions of jQuery: 3.3.1 followed by 1.12.4. this will cause conflicts and issue. Pick one.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned that you adopted this code from someone else. If you want to update it to jQuery, you'll make a lot of changes. You do not have to if you do not want to.

The idea behind a Function is to do something that gets repeated often. So it's better to write one function that can work with 4 sections than write a unique function for each section; unless, each function does something different.

With some minor changes to the HTML you can make better use of `class` attributes and make a lot of your code much smaller and easier to use.

Here is an example.

```js
function displayingListAdultChild(nameSelect) {
  if (nameSelect) {
    $(".display-selection").hide();
    for (var i = 0; i < nameSelect.value; i++) {
      $(".display-selection").eq(i).show();
    }
  }
}

function displayingNumberOfChildAge(nameSelect) {
  if (nameSelect) {
    if (nameSelect.value == 1) {
      $(nameSelect).closest(".display-selection").find(".child-1").show();
      $(nameSelect).closest(".display-selection").find(".child-2").hide();
    } else if (nameSelect.value == 2) {
      $(nameSelect).closest(".display-selection").find(".child-1").show();
      $(nameSelect).closest(".display-selection").find(".child-2").show();
    } else {
      $(nameSelect).closest(".display-selection").find(".child-1").hide();
      $(nameSelect).closest(".display-selection").find(".child-2").hide();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label>Rooms</label>
      <select id="rooms" onchange="displayingListAdultChild(this);" class="form-control">
        <option id="empty">Select</option>
        <option id="firstroom" value="1">1</option>
        <option id="secondroom" value="2">2</option>
        <option id="thirdroom" value="3">3</option>
        <option id="fourthroom" value="4">4</option>
        <option id="fifthroom" value="5">5</option>
        <option id="sixthroom" value="6">6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="displayingFirstAdultChild" style="display:none;" class="display-selection">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
        <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
        <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control">
          <option>select</option>
          <option id="first_child_col" value='1'>1</option>
          <option id="second_child_col" value='2'>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="# child-1" id="displaying_first_child_age" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
          <select class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="# child-2" id="displaying_second_child_age" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
        <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
          <option value='6'>6</option>
          <option value='7'>7</option>
          <option value='8'>8</option>
          <option value='9'>9</option>
          <option value='10'>10</option>
          <option value='11'>11</option>
          <option value='12'>12</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="displayingSecondAdultChild" style="display:none;" class="display-selection">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
        <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
        <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control">
          <option>select</option>
          <option id="sec_room_first_child_col" value='1'>1</option>
          <option id="sec_room_second_child_col" value='2'>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="# child-1" id="displaying_first_child_age_second_room" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
          <select class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="# child-2" id="displaying_second_child_age_second_room" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
          <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
          <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="displayingThirdAdultChild" style="display:none;" class="display-selection">
    <label>Third Room</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
        <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
        <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control">
          <option>select</option>
          <option id="third_room_first_child_col" value='1'>1</option>
          <option id="third_room_second_child_col" value='2'>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="# child-1" id="displaying_first_child_age_third_room" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
          <select class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="# child-2" id="displaying_second_child_age_third_room" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
          <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
          <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="displayingFourthAdultChild" style="display:none;" class="display-selection">
    <label>Fourth Room</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
        <select id="adult_first" name="Room0_Adult" class="form-control">
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
        <select id="selected_child" name="selected_child" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control">
          <option>select</option>
          <option id="fourth_room_first_child_col" value='1'>1</option>
          <option id="fourth_room_second_child_col" value='2'>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="# child-1" id="displaying_first_child_age_fourth_room" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
          <select class="form-control" id="first_child_age" name="first_child_age">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="# child-2" id="displaying_second_child_age_fourth_room" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
          <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
          <select class="form-control" id="second_child_age" name="second_child_age">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of calling each item by it's ID, can make use of class selections and thus, call things in groups or more generally. This allows 1 function to be used from many sections (or rooms).

If this is making no sense at all, I would go back and read or run through some basic jQuery tutorials. Making use of the jQuery framework can help you a lot.